# How can I make right menu block with position:sticky don't overlaid on header?

Tags: html, css, scroll, position, css-position

When I'm scrolling the screen, right menu block overlaid on the header. It happens only when my browser window is small.

**1. Small browser window**
[image]

**2. Big browser window**
[image]

[3. My code](https://codepen.io/Van245/pen/ExKOojb)

```
<header> <ul> <li><a href="">text</a></li> <li><a href="">text</a></li> <li><a href="">text</a></li> <li><a href="">text</a></li> <li><a href="">text</a></li> </ul> </header> <div class="content"> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus, illo accusamus corrupti facere exercitationem quis amet aperiam ipsam illum ex laudantium nesciunt dicta iure qui tempore id at, alias repellat! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus, illo accusamus corrupti facere exercitationem quis amet aperiam ipsam illum ex laudantium nesciunt dicta iure qui tempore id at, alias repellat! Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam voluptatibus incidunt ipsa, tempore fuga veniam et consectetur alias nulla adipisci voluptas! Mollitia, excepturi voluptatibus animi aliquid numquam perferendis architecto accusantium. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Itaque inventore, cumque architecto asperiores a soluta deserunt cupiditate quae quisquam necessitatibus commodi, aliquam reprehenderit adipisci sequi iste fugiat, recusandae voluptatem distinctio. </p> </div> <div class="wrapper"> <div class="left_content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non placeat explicabo minus vero quae illum debitis facere sint consequatur, quia, perspiciatis reprehenderit quas eligendi, reiciendis repellendus sit officia provident. Porro! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem fugiat, vel totam ullam quaerat asperiores quidem blanditiis optio natus quos laborum deserunt repellendus quod dignissimos excepturi non iure ducimus ipsa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non placeat explicabo minus vero quae illum debitis facere sint consequatur, quia, perspiciatis reprehenderit quas eligendi, reiciendis repellendus sit officia provident. Porro! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem fugiat, vel totam ullam quaerat asperiores quidem blanditiis optio natus quos laborum deserunt repellendus quod dignissimos excepturi non iure ducimus ipsa.</div> <div class="ad_block"> <ul> <li><a href="">text</a></li> <li><a href="">text</a></li> <li><a href="">text</a></li> <li><a href="">text</a></li> <li><a href="">text</a></li> </ul> </div> </div>
header { width: 100%; height: 50px; background: yellow; display: flex; justify-content: center; position: fixed; } header ul li { display: inline-block; list-style: none; margin-right: 30px; } .content { padding-top: 50px; } .wrapper { display: flex; width: 700px; margin: 0 auto; height: 900px; } .left_content { width: 95%; height: 800px; background: #ffdede; padding: 10px; } .ad_block { display: inline-block; width: 40%; height: 400px; top: 58px; position: sticky; background: yellowgreen; }
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you in advance:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sticky element sticks only within its parent, this is why at some point (when one scrolled enough so the bottom of the parent appears) the element will start scrolling with its parent and overlaid your menu).

There are probably other solutions but I think the fact that the menu is fixed is not helping. Here is a solution with grid

```css
main {
  display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: calc(100vh - 16px); /* -16px because the body has a 8px padding */
}

.container {
  overflow: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60% 40%;
}

.content {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 30px; /* gap with flex doesn't work with Safari */
}

header ul li {
  /* display: inline-block; */ /* no need because parent is flex */
  list-style: none;
  /* margin-right: 30px; */ /* no need because of gap */
}

.left_content {
  /* width: 95%; */ /* no need because parent is grid */
  height: 800px;
  background: #ffdede;
  padding: 10px;
}

.ad_block {
/* display: inline-block; */ /* no need because parent is grid */
/*  width: 40%; */ /* no need because parent is grid */
  height: 400px;
  background: yellowgreen;
}

.ad_block  > ul {
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">text</a></li>
      <li><a href="">text</a></li>
      <li><a href="">text</a></li>
      <li><a href="">text</a></li>
      <li><a href="">text</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus, illo accusamus corrupti facere exercitationem quis amet aperiam ipsam illum ex laudantium nesciunt dicta iure qui tempore id at, alias repellat!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus, illo accusamus corrupti facere exercitationem quis amet aperiam ipsam illum ex laudantium nesciunt dicta iure qui tempore id at, alias repellat! Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam voluptatibus incidunt ipsa, tempore fuga veniam et consectetur alias nulla adipisci voluptas! Mollitia, excepturi voluptatibus animi aliquid numquam perferendis architecto accusantium. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Itaque inventore, cumque architecto asperiores a soluta deserunt cupiditate quae quisquam necessitatibus commodi, aliquam reprehenderit adipisci sequi iste fugiat, recusandae voluptatem distinctio.
    </p>
  </div>
  
    <div class="left_content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non placeat explicabo minus vero quae illum debitis facere sint consequatur, quia, perspiciatis reprehenderit quas eligendi, reiciendis repellendus sit officia provident. Porro! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem fugiat, vel totam ullam quaerat asperiores quidem blanditiis optio natus quos laborum deserunt repellendus quod dignissimos excepturi non iure ducimus ipsa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non placeat explicabo minus vero quae illum debitis facere sint consequatur, quia, perspiciatis reprehenderit quas eligendi, reiciendis repellendus sit officia provident. Porro! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem fugiat, vel totam ullam quaerat asperiores quidem blanditiis optio natus quos laborum deserunt repellendus quod dignissimos excepturi non iure ducimus ipsa.</div>
    <div class="ad_block">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="">text</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Even like this at some point the `.ad_block` will start to be scrolled. This is because you've set (different) height value to `div.left_content` and `div.ad_block`